# Quais as diferenças entre Thread e promise

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, promises

Sou mais do mundo desktop, mas estou querendo saber mais de WEB.
E gostaria de saber se tem diferença entre promise do javascript e thread do C#.

Comment: Tem diferença sim, são duas coisas completamente distintas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thread e Promise são coisas completamente diferentes.

O motor que roda o js no browser é single-thread, como o javascript é guiado por eventos geralmente não trabalhamos diretamente com a thread e sim com o eventloop.

Promise é um recurso que veio para acabar com a chamada excessiva de callbacks, onde vai executar um processamento de forma assíncrona. Segundo a documentação: Um Promise (de "promessa") representa um valor que pode estar disponível agora, no futuro ou nunca.

Um promise pode assumir 4 estados. ( pendente, realizada, rejeitado, estabelicida)

Para ver as informações completas, acesse a documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise